# could not find the main class program will exit while installing oracle 11g client on 32 bit Windows 7?

Tags: java, oracle, windows-7, installation, oracleclient

I am trying to install Oracle Client 32 bit on Windows 7 32 bit operating system When I run the setup.exe I am getting the error "could not find the main class program will exit" I have installed latest java version 7 even thou still the problem is existing, can any one help me on this?

Note: I have set the in PATH as C:\Program Files\Java\jre7

Comment: is it possible you tried running the installation from within the zip file ?

Comment: No, I didn't try it I have already extracted folder

Comment: I'm not sure but isn't the path something like "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin" ? That's where java.exe (and other executables) are located.

Comment: This issue is resolved, I have downloaded the new copy of Oracle Client then it's worked fine for me. My client software was corrupted

Comment: For me the setup was corrupted, i downloaded again and it worked.